# How to fix step size in do loop?

Tags: numerical-value

I apply the following command:

```
Do[Print[var[u] = u], {u, -1, 1, 0.1}]
```

It produces out put. But when i recall the value var[-0.4] as below:

```
In[2]:= var[-0.4]

Out[2]= var[-0.4]
```

It produces var[-0.4] instead of the value.
It can be handled if i replace step size 0.1 by 1/10 but i want to work with decimal point form.
It may be due to floating point. If any one may help to give a good suggestion on it. It will be highluy appreciated.

Comment: Use exact numbers and add a definition to `var` to handle inexact numbers: ``Do[var[u] = u, {u, -1, 1, 1/10}]; var[r_Real] := var[Rationalize[r]]``

Answer (score 2):

It is a precision issue

```
Clear[var]

Do[var[u] = u, {u, -1, 1, 0.1}]

DownValues[var][[15]]//FullForm

(*  RuleDelayed[HoldPattern[var[0.40000000000000013`]], 0.40000000000000013`]  *)
```

Consequently, you would need to enter

```
var[0.40000000000000013]

(*  0.4  *)

%//InputForm

(*  0.40000000000000013  *)
```

To avoid the precision issue, use exact numbers

```
Clear[var]

Do[var[u] = u,{u, -1, 1, 1/10}]
```

Then

```
var[4/10] == var[2/5] == 2/5

(*  True  *)
```